# What happens if the same object instance is attached multiple times to SplObjectStorage?

Tags: php, storage, spl, splobjectstorage

Or in other words, should I bother checking whether it already is in the set before attaching it?

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage();

foreach($arrayOfObjects as $primaryObject) {
    $subObject=$primaryObject->getSubObject();  //It is possible that a given instance of $subObject might be used in more than one $primaryObject
    if(!$s->contains($subObject)) {
        $s->attach($subObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "key" used internally by `SplObjectStorage` for each attached object is the hash of the given object (the same as returned by [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)).

Each call to `attach` will effectively overwrite any existing object in the storage with the same hash (which should only happen if you're providing the same object), so there's no need to call `contains` before attaching an object.

`SplObjectStorage::attach($object)` effectively means the same as

```
$storage[spl_object_hash($object)] = $object;
```

if you were using an array as your store instead.

Full demo:

```
class Foo {}
$foo = new Foo;
$s = new SplObjectStorage;

echo $s->count(); // 0

$s->attach($foo);
echo $s->count(); // 1

$s->attach($foo);
echo $s->count(); // 1

$s->detach($foo);
echo $s->count(); // 0
```

See https://3v4l.org/Rft7i

Comment: Thanks,  I thought so, but couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: Yeah, the SPL documentation is... patchy